# Initialize C++ std::array without length

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, stdarray

If a `std::array` is defined I need to write something like this

```
std::array<int,3> my_array {1,5,3};
```

In my option this violates the `DRY` principle (Don't repeat yourself), since I need to specify the length of the array explicitly and it need to corresponds to the length of the initializer list.

Is there a way to write something like

```
std::array<int> my_array {1,5,3};
```

and the constant length of the array is deduced form the length of the initializer list?

Comment: Use C++17 and deduction guides. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides

Comment: Agreed. While the referenced duplicate shows ways that you *can* do it in c++11, I'd recommend that you don't bother, as it is fixed properly in c++17.